# Why can't the subs function of the sympy replace the value of the symbol sometimes？

Tags: sympy

I have the following code：

```
u_ini = 0.1
v_ini = 0.1
z_ini = 0.1  # 初始化三个拉格朗日乘子

q = 0

lis = list(range(2))
u = list(sp.symbols('u:{}'.format(len(lis))))
v = list(sp.symbols('v:{}'.format(len(lis))))
z = sp.symbols('z')
p = list(sp.symbols('p:{}'.format(len(lis))))

lag1 = 0
lag2 = 0
lag3 = 0

p_symbol_sum = np.sum(p)

for i in range(k):
    if i < k-1:
        lag1 += B*ts_ratio[i]*sp.log(1+g[i]*p[i]/(sgm_2+g[i]*np.sum(p[i+1:k])),2)-q*(af_eff*p[i]+Pc-eh_eff*(1-ts_ratio[i])*g[i]*p_symbol_sum)
        lag2 -= u[i] * (R_min - ts_ratio[i] * B * sp.log(1 + g[i] * p[i] / (sgm_2 + g[i] * np.sum(p[i + 1:k])),2))
    elif i == k-1:
        lag1 += B*ts_ratio[i]*sp.log(1+g[i]*p[i]/(sgm_2+g[i]*p[i]),2)-q*(af_eff*p[i]+Pc-eh_eff*(1-ts_ratio[i])*g[i]*p_symbol_sum)
        lag2 -= u[i] * (R_min - ts_ratio[i] * B * sp.log(1+g[i]*p[i]/(sgm_2+g[i]*p[i]),2))
    lag3 -= v[i] * (E_min - (1 - ts_ratio[i])*eh_eff*g[i]*p_symbol_sum) + z * (p[i] - p_max)
lag_fun = lag1 + lag2 + lag3
print("lag_fun:",lag_fun)

for i in range(k):
    lag_fun.subs([(u[i],u_ini), (v[i],v_ini), (z,z_ini), (p[i],p_ini)]).evalf()
print("lag_fun:",lag_fun)
```

Why does the value of the expression not change after I count down the subs of the second line。
This is the output of the program. The first line is the output before using subs. The second is the output after using subs. Why hasn't it changed?

```
lag_fun: -u0*(-0.5*log(0.0410609879149758*p0/(0.0410609879149758*p1 + 0.001) + 1)/log(2) + 2) - u1*(-0.5*log(0.0123909311217172*p1/(0.0123909311217172*p1 + 0.001) + 1)/log(2) + 2) - v0*(-0.00205304939574879*p0 - 0.00205304939574879*p1 + 0.2) - v1*(-0.000619546556085859*p0 - 0.000619546556085859*p1 + 0.2) - z*(p0 - 20) - z*(p1 - 20) + 0.5*log(0.0410609879149758*p0/(0.0410609879149758*p1 + 0.001) + 1)/log(2) + 0.5*log(0.0123909311217172*p1/(0.0123909311217172*p1 + 0.001) + 1)/log(2)
lag_fun: -u0*(-0.5*log(0.0410609879149758*p0/(0.0410609879149758*p1 + 0.001) + 1)/log(2) + 2) - u1*(-0.5*log(0.0123909311217172*p1/(0.0123909311217172*p1 + 0.001) + 1)/log(2) + 2) - v0*(-0.00205304939574879*p0 - 0.00205304939574879*p1 + 0.2) - v1*(-0.000619546556085859*p0 - 0.000619546556085859*p1 + 0.2) - z*(p0 - 20) - z*(p1 - 20) + 0.5*log(0.0410609879149758*p0/(0.0410609879149758*p1 + 0.001) + 1)/log(2) + 0.5*log(0.0123909311217172*p1/(0.0123909311217172*p1 + 0.001) + 1)/log(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`subs` doesn't change anything in place, you have to capture the result for the same reason that this loop fails to change `x`:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> for i in range(10): x + 1
>>> x
0
```

So it must be

```
lag_fun = lag_fun.subs(etc...)
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.